# Launching background process in RIA service

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I have a silverlight/RIA service application and in that, after I save the data using EF/RIA services. I would like to start one task that might take more than 30 seconds or so to finish. What is the best way I can start a task without hold the service thread? The user might issue multiple save command and each one need to trigger separate tasks.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start up a [Background Worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) or if you can/are using Silverlight 5 you could use the TPL.